# Почему объекты Javascript не работают в onclick?

Tags: ajax, javascript

Всем привет, прошу помощи, вот скрипт:

```
var article = {
    delete: function (id) {
        $.post('?action=admin', {
            act: 'delete',
            aid: id
        }, function (a) {
            alert(a);
        })
    },
    edit: {
        now: function (id) {..........
        },
        withadmin: function (id) {
            window.location = '?action=admin&act=article_edit&id=' + id;
        }
    }
}
```

В теге `<script></script>` работает, а вот если напишу `onclick="article.edit.now('1');"` ничего не работает, почему?

Если я напишу так:

```
<script>
$('#edit_news').click(function () {
    article.edit.now('1');
});
</script>
```

Работает, если напишу

```
<a href="" onlick='article.edit.now('1')'>Редактировать</a>
```

Не работает.

Comment: Напишите код - когда работает и когда не работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Напишите так:

```
<a href="#" onclick="article.edit.now('1');">Редактировать</a>
```

И вероятно будет работать

Comment: А еще не **LICK**, а **CLICK** :D

onLick уместнее к другим `"объектам"` применять! )))

Comment: @DemoS, действительно, не заметил))